# How can I save/overwrite my TensorFlow/Keras model ONLY when validation accuracy improves?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

There is a lot already out there about saving models, but I'm struggling to work out how I can save my model only when it improves upon `val_accuracy`. My model looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Embedding(numberOfWords,
                           embedding_vector_length, input_length=1000),
    keras.layers.LSTM(128),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5), loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

During training, I want to save the model after the first epoch. Then, after every epoch, if `val_accuracy` has been improved upon, I want to overwrite the old model with the new one.

How do I do this?

Comment: I will also recommend you to check out `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` if you wish to stop training when accuracy reached at certain threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to define a Callback-List and enter it into the `model.fit` declaration: [Keras_fit](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) In this example its just safing the `best weigths`, so its actually overwriting the old ones, and safes it into an `hdf5` format. Hope that solved your problem :)

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

filepath="weights.best.hdf5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200,,callbacks=callbacks_list, batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: this will not save the model when accuracy reach a certain threshold accuracy,it will just save the model when training end

Comment: Okay,I think this the solution,as the user wanted the best model to be saved,this will do it

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat actually it will save after every epoch; the `save_best_only` will not override if the val_loss starts increasing again. See doc for more details:https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint